# How can I use AS and the alias in WHERE?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

HI i want to check if  NumOfSpeakLanguages has more than 10 languages, how can I do:
here the code:

```
SELECT country.Name,country.Capital,COUNT(DISTINCT countrylanguage.Language) AS NumOfSpeakLanguages
FROM country,countrylanguage
WHERE country.Code=countrylanguage.CountryCode AND NumOfSpeakLanguages >10
GROUP BY country.Name
```

here the error code:

```
SELECT country.Name,country.Capital,COUNT(DISTINCT countrylanguage.Language) AS NumOfSpeakLanguages
FROM country,countrylanguage
WHERE country.Code=countrylanguage.CountryCode AND NumOfSpeakLanguages >10
GROUP BY country.Name LIMIT 0, 25

#1054 - Unknown column'NumOfSpeakLanguages' in 'where clause'
```

Thank you!

Comment: LIMIT without an ORDER BY? Doesn't it matter which 25 rows you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HAVING` clause for aggregate function conditions:

```
SELECT country.Name,country.Capital,COUNT(DISTINCT countrylanguage.Language) AS NumOfSpeakLanguages
FROM country,
JOIN countrylanguage
  ON country.Code = countrylanguage.CountryCode
GROUP BY country.Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT countrylanguage.Language) > 10
LIMIT 0, 25
```

@Andrew Brēza commented: You could also say `HAVING NumOfSpeakLanguages >10`. (Which is a MySQL special.)

Also doing explicit `JOIN`!

Alternatively, do the aggregation in a a derived table:

```
select * from
(
    SELECT country.Name,country.Capital,COUNT(DISTINCT countrylanguage.Language) AS NumOfSpeakLanguages
    FROM country,
    JOIN countrylanguage
      ON country.Code = countrylanguage.CountryCode
    GROUP BY country.Name
) dt
where NumOfSpeakLanguages > 10
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: Beat me to it. You could also say `HAVING NumOfSpeakLanguages >10` which will keep working as you'd expect even if you change the *EDIT* definition of NumOfSpeakLanguages.

Comment: @AndrewBrēza, yes, I forgot that MySQL special trick. (My answer is ANSI SQL and portable.)

Comment: I have a new job and am moving from MySQL to SQL Server, so I'm developing a new appreciation of portable code :-)

Comment: @jarlh I am a beginner of Mysql, can you explain me why I have to use explict JOIN instead of Where? thanks

Comment: @ric, you don't have to, but you really should learn it ASAP. It's easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed! (I switched to it after 20 years of WHERE, and I'll never go back!)